# app.config in DEBUG,INFO, etc

Tags: c#, debugging, logging, app-config, log-level

I have a problem with `app.config` in C#.

I wrote an `app.config` with `key` and `value=DEBUG`, while in `main` I wrote

```
DEBUG,INFO,WARN AND ERROR.
```

The problem is that the value doesn't work and it's printing the `main` into my log without considering the level.

This is my app config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="FolderName" value="C:\Users\mpilas\Desktop\logs\" />
<add key="FileSize" venter code herealue="10240" />
<add key="LogNameType" value="Date"/> <!--Value can be Size or "Date" -->
<add key="Level" value='DEBUG'/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

My `main` is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;


namespace ConsoleApplication8 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                LogWriter.Write("Hello", Severity.DEBUG);
                LogWriter.Write("Hello", Severity.INFO);
                LogWriter.Write("Hello", Severity.WARNING);
                LogWriter.Write("Hello", Severity.ERROR);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have one more class with the name `:LogWriter`.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8 {
    public enum Severity { ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG };

    public class LogWriter {
        private static string _folder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderName"];
        private static long _fileSize = int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileSize"]);
        private static string kindOfType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogNameType"];

        static LogWriter() {}

        private static string GetFileNameByDate() {
            string dateName= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return  _folder + dateName + ".log";
        }

        private static string GetFileNameBySize() {
            string name = "";
            int counter = 0;

            do {
                if (counter == 0) { name = _folder + kindOfType + ".log"; }
                else {name = _folder + kindOfType + "-" + counter + ".log"; }
                if (File.Exists(name) {
                    counter++;
                    FileInfo realFile = new FileInfo(name);
                    if (realFile.Length > _fileSize) { 
                        name = _folder + kindOfType + "-" + counter + ".log";
                    }
                    else { break; }
                }
                else { break; }
            } while (true);
            return name;
        }


        private static string GetFileName() {
            clearFiles();
            if(kindOfType == "Size") { return GetFileNameBySize(); }
            else { 
              if(kindOfType == "Date") { return GetFileNameByDate(); }
            }
            return "";
        }

        public static void Write(string messgae, Severity severity) {
            try {
                string file = GetFileName();
                StreamWriter log = new StreamWriter(file, true);
                log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + severity.ToString() + ": [" + messgae + "]");
                log.Flush();
                log.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception) {}
        }

        private static void clearFiles() {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(_folder);
            foreach (string file in files) {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                if (fi.LastAccessTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)) { fi.Delete(); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How should I treat the `key=level` and its value on my application?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  You've not provided enough detail in your question for someone to answer it: the code that actually *does* something with the `Severity` value will be inside the `LogWriter` class.  You should probably add that class if you want to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may be better off using the existing log scaffolding provided in `System.Diagnostics` - implement your own [`TraceListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t.aspx), which can take care of your 14 day rolling logs etc, then all you need to do is register your trace listener via `app.config`, then configure your trace levels using a [trace switch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2007/06/07/adding-trace-to-a-net-application-and-listening-to-it.aspx).

*Note that the `traceSwitch` instance in the backing code is controlled by the `<add name="TraceLevelSwitch" value="0" />` config field.*

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <switches>
            <!--  0-off, 1-error, 2-warn, 3-info, 4-verbose. -->
            <add name="TraceLevelSwitch" value="0" />
        </switches>
        <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
            <listeners>
                <add name="myListener" type="MorPilasTraceListener" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

---

```
private static TraceSwitch traceSwitch = new TraceSwitch("TraceLevelSwitch", null);

private static void LogInfo(string message)
{
    if(traceSwitch.TraceInfo)
        Trace.TraceInformation(message);
}
```